# Multiple array manipulations and merging

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am an amateur programmer that needs the help of a real one to resolve this beautiful problem, because I must admit that I am really stuck on this one!

In my database I have a « **tslines** » table that contains a value (**sum_week**) for a given week(**startdate**) and a given contract(**contract_id**)

The fields that are important are : **sum_week, user_id , startdate and contract_id**

I also have a « **users** » table, the important values are « **first_name, last_name** »

I have many workers that have worked on a contract, at different times (**startdate, represents the first day of the week**)

Example (table below): I can have 3 lines for worker A, and 2 lines for worker B

For some week(startdate), it can happend that no one worked on the contract

I want to show a table with those informations, for contract_id=3(ex) (this field is in tslines table) :

[image]

**sum_week** is a field, I don't want to recalculate with a SQL query

I don’t want to run a query for each weeks to check for each user if he worked on a contract because that would become a problem if I have ex : 30 weeks with 30 users that worked on the project..

I started by building an array of all possible « startdate »

```
//Selects min and max startdate of the tslines, use $dates->maxdate and ->mindate
$dates = $contract->tslines()->whereIsOfficial(true)->select(DB::raw('MAX(startdate) as maxdate, MIN(startdate) as mindate'))->first();

//Define first date declared in tslines
$loopdate = Carbon::parse($dates->mindate);
$maxdt = Carbon::parse($dates->maxdate);

//While loop to create array of date ranges from min to max
$date_count = 0;
$daterange = array();
while($loopdate->gt($maxdt) == false)
{
   $daterange[] = $loopdate->format('Y-m-d');
   $loopdate->addDays(7);
   $date_count++;
}
```

I know I have to do some array manipulations but I really don’t know from where to start, even witht the queries..

I can get all the related tslines of contract by doing:

> $contract->tslines()->get()

But I dont't know how to build an array that contains user information and all the startdate (even if he didn't work that week)

Can anybody give me some hints.. It would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!

Raphaël

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from what we know.

We know which users have worked on which contracts and on what date.

With your function above, we have the max date and the min date a user has started working on a contract.

**Solution:**

```
$tslines = $contract->tslines()->orderBy('user_id','ASC')->orderBy('startdate','ASC')->get();
//I didn't see any relationship calls to the user's object, so you'll have to add one of your own. I am assuming, your `tslines` has a relationship `user` here.
$userListResult = $contract->tslines()->with('user')->orderBy('user_id','ASC')->select(\Db::raw('distinct("user_id")')->get();

$dates = $contract->tslines()->whereIsOfficial(true)->select(DB::raw('MAX(startdate) as maxdate, MIN(startdate) as mindate'))->first();
$minDate = Carbon::parse($dates->mindate);
$maxDate = Carbon::parse($dates->maxdate);

//we flatten the array for future use.

$userList = array();
foreach($userListResult as $l)
{
    $userList[$l->user_id] = $l->user->first_name.' '.$l->user->last_name;
}

//Assuming you are printing a table in blade

<table>
   <?php
        //Print the table headers
        echo"<tr>
                <td>User</td>";
        $currDate = clone($minDate);

        do
        {
            echo "<td>".$currDate->format('Y-m-d')."</td>";
            $currDate->addDay();
        }
        while($currDate->diffInDays($maxDate) !== 0);

        echo "</tr>";

        //Print each user's row
        foreach($userlist as $userid => $username)
        {

            echo "<tr>
                    <td>
                        $username
                    </td>";
            $currDate = clone($minDate);

            //loop through all the dates in range (min to max date)
            do
            {
                $foundDate = false;
                //We check if user has worked on that day
                foreach($tslines as $row)
                {
                    if($row->user_id === $userid && $row->startdate->format('Y-m-d') === $currDate->format('Y-m-d'))
                    {
                        //Print result if startdate & userid matches
                        echo "<td>{$row->sum_week}</td>";
                        $foundDate = true;
                        //Get out of the loops
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!$foundDate)
                {
                    echo "<td>X (didn't work)</td>";
                }
                $currDate->addDay();
            }
            while($currDate->diffInDays($maxDate) !== 0);
            echo "</tr>";
        }


   ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I will slightly modify it to make it MVC but you are the real brain for the logic of this code!!
Thank you very much @Mysteryos for taking the time to help me, you have solved my problem :) BIG TANKS!!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Once you figure out in which order you need your data, it's just a matter of putting up the pieces together.